# How to duplicate tensorflow network state in memory for retrieval after parameter update?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow graph with several modules and I would like to reuse the *previous network state* from one of them (before parameter update) to evaluate an input *at the next state* (after parameter update).

**Example**

Consider the toy example where I would like to essentially duplicate `network_B` at timestep `t`, to use at the next training step `t+1`:

```
def network_A(x):
    A1 = tf.matmul(x, A_W1) + A_b1
    return tf.nn.relu(A1)

def network_B(x):
    B1 = tf.matmul(x, B_W1) + B_b1
    Z1 = tf.nn.relu(B1)
    B2 = tf.matmul(Z1, B_W2) + B_b2
    return B2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, x_dim])
x_2 = network_A(x)

# Evaluate input x_2 with current state of network
y_hatB_current = network_B(x)

# Evaluate same input x_2 with past state of network
y_hatB_past = network_B_past(x) # 

# Get some loss
loss = ...
```

Then, once both have been evaluated, save the current state of network as the new past state, and optimize only the current state:

```
# Save state of parameters
network_B_past = network_B  # (How do I do this efficiently?)

# Optimize the current state
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, var_list=current_vars)
```

**Details**

So, at each training step there should exist two versions of `network_B` available to evaluate inputs:

1. `network_B` at timestep `t-1`(past state)
2. `network_B` at timestep `t`(current state)

In between the two training steps there was a parameter update, so the weights should be slightly different between the two, but they should be identical otherwise. Then, after the new inputs are evaluated, the current state replaces the past state, and another training step occurs updating the network.

I know I can save and reload checkpoints in tensorflow, but this seem too inefficient for my use case since it needs to occur at every training step. What is an effective way to achieve this network cloning step so that I maintain a copy that persists across states?

Tensorflow Version: 1.5

Answer (score 1):

I would create the network twice using a function `create_graph` under different variable scopes: one for the current and one for backup. Note, this doubles the memory consumption.

Then all you need is a custom `sync_op`. A MWE is

```
import tensorflow as tf


def copy_vars(src_scope, dst_scope):
    src_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=src_scope)
    dst_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=dst_scope)

    update_op = []

    for src_var in src_vars:
        for dst_var in dst_vars:
            if src_var.name.replace('%s' % src_scope, '') == dst_var.name.replace('%s' % dst_scope, ''):
                assert dst_var.shape == src_var.shape
                print("  copy: add assign {} -> {}".format(src_var.name, dst_var.name))
                update_op.append(dst_var.assign(src_var))
    return tf.group(update_op)


def create_graph(name, x, use_c=False, uses_gradient_updates=True):

    var_setter = lambda x: x  # noqa
    if uses_gradient_updates:
        var_setter = lambda x: tf.stop_gradient(x)  # noqa

    with tf.variable_scope(name, custom_getter=var_setter):
        a = tf.Variable([1], dtype=tf.float32)
        b = tf.Variable([1], dtype=tf.float32)
        result = x + a + b
        if use_c:
            # create dummy variable just to show both graphs do not need to be exactly the same
            c = tf.Variable([1], dtype=tf.float32)
        return result, a, b

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

c1, a1, b1 = create_graph('original', x, use_c=True)
c2, a2, b2 = create_graph('backup', x, use_c=False)

sync_op = copy_vars('original', 'backup')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run([c1, c2], {x: 5}))  # in sync

    sess.run(a1.assign([3]))  # update your graph either by tf.train.Adam or by:
    print(sess.run([c1, c2], {x: 5}))  # out of sync

    sess.run(sync_op)  # do syncing
    print(sess.run([c1, c2], {x: 5}))  # in sync
```

The `custom_getter` can help to prevent gradient updates.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well in the example you gave, but is there a way to use `custom_getter` in the same way with `tf.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable`?

Comment: `tf.get_variable` and `tf.Variable` only differ in the way they are (re-)using ressources. It work for both.